# Why two resistors at Gate side of IGBT

Tags: microcontroller, rectifier, inverter

[image: schematic of single phase bridge rectifier]

Why two resistors(R5 and R9) are required at the gate side of IGBT Q3? According to me they are used as potential divider, but can any one tell why it is needed over there? In datasheet it is clear that voltage at pin 13 of L6386D can be varied from -3 to Vboot-18.

Comment: If those values are correct, R5 is not much of a contributor to a divider.  It is more likely that it is there to limit the inrush current to the insulated gate of the IGBT.  The diode around it is to allow for fast discharging of the gate.

Answer (score 4):

R5 controls the gate current (and possibly prevents damaging current from flowing back to the driving circuit if there is some source inductance). It slows the turn-on, and the diode shunts it so the IGBT turns off quickly.

R9 (gate to emitter) is just there to keep the IGBT 'off' if the driver gets disconnected, removed from the socket, or goes high impedance. Without that, you could get shoot-through under that condition which would destroy the IGBTs- since they're in series across the supply voltage. A 0.1 cent resistor is cheap insurance.

Comment: also known as ringing due to parasitic inductance in driver-gate-source circuit and the gate capacitance.